# Error TypeError: i28.ɵd is not a constructor in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-aot

I get the follow error while running the angular application (hitting application url in browser) in AOT mode using **ng serve --aot** command. Please not that I get no error while building application in aot mode. I get this error in browser when i hit application url.

```
`ERROR TypeError: i28.ɵd is not a constructor
    at eval (app.module.ngfactory.js:94)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10955)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10897)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10879)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10947)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10897)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10879)
    at _createClass (core.js:10920)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10894)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10879)`
```

Any solutions for this problem will be helpful.

Comment: Does i28.ɵd ring any bell though? Generally this is most likely an import issue, the app tries to create an instance of a provider that is not actually available, probably due to a missing import. Some additional code or information could help solving the riddle!

Comment: My application works perfectly fine with **ng serve** command. I guess it is aot compilation that is causing problems. I get the above error while hitting the browser for application url.

Comment: Still hard to say though - which external modules are you using exactly? Maybe simply add your app.module to your original question!

Comment: @OClyde Yes you were right. The problem got fixed by migrating to newer version of angular-oauth2-oidc (moved from 3.1.0 to 3.1.4).

Comment: Glad to hear this! Added the explanation as an answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is most likely an import issue, the app tries to create an instance of a provider that is not actually available, probably due to a missing import.